# How to make space between <p> elements

Tags: html, css

I'd like to put some space between the `<p>`s en the E's. But don't know how to do it without smashing my spacebar.

```css
.footer_box p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer_box">
  <p>Aantal M²:</p>
  <p>Schuren:</p>
  <p style="float:left;">Behandeling:</p>
  <p>E</p>
  <p>Afwerking:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you should not use p in this case .. consider span element

Comment: But @temaniafif then everything goes next to eachother. And if i use P's they go under eachother like i need it to. You know a fix?

Comment: use a `<br>` element after the `P`, thats what it was invented for, creating a new line. use a more correct element for the use case `P` is a Paragraph, which is not what you are representing. that way, you will not need to redefine the `P` element.

Comment: You have to add span inside of <p> and </p> to make space between elements

Answer (score 3):

Add the E within a span inside the `P` tag and then add padding the the span tag like so:-

```css
p span {
  padding-left: 40px
}
```

```html
   <div id="footer_box">
    <p>Aantal M²:</p>
    <p>Schuren:</p>
    <p>Behandeling:<span>E</span></p>
    <p>Afwerking:</p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this method of html, i hope it will help you.

```css
.footer_box p{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <div id="footer_box">
    <p>Aantal M²:</p>
    <p>Schuren:</p>
    <p>Behandeling: <span>E</span></p>  
    <p>Afwerking:</p>
   </div>
```